# joomla help with template and admin

Tags: joomla, joomla-template

I have been handed a joomla site and i dont know anything about joomla (yeah i know).

Ok so im in the admin. I have looked at the template and the edit html for the template.

There is text in or related to this element
Code:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="xhtml" />
```

. How do i edit or access this to change the text in or related to this element?

likewise with this element:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="partners" style="xhtml" />
```

Any help is going to be GREATLY APPRECIATED.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this in module manager of admin section. Just to to module manager where all the modules are listed, click on module which has position search and edit the parameters of module which will be on right side of the module.

Answer (score 0):

This means that he created module positions, with the name "search", and "partners".
Go to your modules section, and find those modules, that are in the search or partners positions, and edit them.